# OpenCV Android: Obtaining coordinates of pixels lighted at specific color

Tags: android, opencv

I am working on an app using OpenCV249 on android and would like to find means to obtain the coordinates of the pixels that are lighted at a specific color relative to the image. For instance if I draw a green dot using android's canvas and drawables on an image, is there a way to obtain the coordinates of that green dot relative to the image by means of finding out the pixels that are lighted at that specific color?

And if this process is extended to more complicated random sketches, ie circles or rectangles, is there a way to obtain those points as well? Imagine multiple circles/rectangles drawn and different colors, I need a way to obtain the coordinates of those circles/rectangles I've drawn using different colors.

Because I am developing for android, I appreciate any advise that comes from android perspective pls, thanks!!

Comment: If you're drawing the green dot, don't you already know the coordinates?

Comment: @MikeM. well yes, I can simply do getX() and getY() to obtain the coordinates of that dot. Pardon maybe I should rephrase my question alittle (I will edit my question). I am interested to obtain the coordinates by searching for the pixels that are lighted up in that specific color. Imagine multiple dots draw at different colors, I want a way that is capable of doing that. and similarly if its a rectangle or circle, possible for me to do that operation?